# How does the Marauder's new set bonus work with Kridershot?

Tags: diablo-iii

The new Marauder's set has the following set bonus.

- The Demon Hunter's Hatred generator skills deal 100% additional damage for every active Sentry

The unique item [Kridershot](http://Companion%20summons%20all%20six%20types%20of%20animals%20at%20once%20(2%20pieces)%20Each%20Sentry%20will%20shoot%20one%20of%20the%20Hatred%20spender%20skills%20currently%20equipped%20by%20the%20Demon%20Hunter%20(Elemental%20Arrow,%20Cluster%20Arrow,%20Multishot,%20Impale%20or%20Chakram),%20fully%20benefiting%20from%20runes%20and%20enhancements,%20every%20time%20the%20Demon%20Hunter%20uses%20them,%20at%20the%20same%20target%20(4%20pieces)%20The%20Demon%20Hunter's%20Hatred%20generator%20(Primary)%20skills,%20Chakram,%20Cluster%20Arrow,%20Elemental%20Arrow,%20Impale,%20and%20Multishot%20deal%20100%25%20additional%20damage%20for%20every%20active%20Sentry%20(6%20pieces)) now makes my skill Elemental Arrow generate Hatred.

Would this 100% damage per Sentry carry over to my Elemental Arrow as well now?

Comment: That *would* be slightly OP I think, but I have no clue if it works or not.

Comment: I know, which is why I'm curious to find an answer somewhere. I found a slightly weak Kridershot the other day, but if I can do 100% damage per active Sentry, it would make the choice rather clear.

Comment: You'd need someone with both the set and the item to test it, I haven't completed a non-blacksmith set *ever*, nor do I have a Kridershot, nor  a Demon Hunter at some kind of good level to test it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the Marauder's 6 bonus it states :

> Your generator, Elemental Arrow, Chakram, Impale, Multishot and
>   Cluster Arrow deal 100% increase damage for every active Sentry.

[image]

So you don't even have to worry about Kridershot turning elemental arrow into a generator.

**As of patch 2.2** : The new [Unhallowed Essence Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/accursed-visage) does count Elemental Arrow as generator if you are using a Kridershot. This means that Elemental Arrow will regen 1 discipline per shot and gain 15% damage for each point of discipline you have.

Comment: OH! There you go. Did they change what it said? I remember just seeing "Your generators" only. Thanks for guiding the blind :D

Comment: Do they stack? Rather than carry?

Comment: What is more interesting is the 4 item bonus. We know Elemental Arrow is still considered a Hatred 'spender' but it really isn't, with Kridershot.

Comment: @ChaseC I thought the same thing until I read this question.

Comment: Virus, it stacks. So 3 active sentries is 300% damage. NSX, Elemental Arrow is casted from all the Sentries everytime with this bow! It's insane!

Comment: @ChaseC it works until a certain level of GR. I've managed 42 with a Kridershot based built but it loses its efficiency (lack of damage) on higher GR. For now for gr 45+ you'll need an ancient crossbow ;)

Comment: @WizLiz Like....an ancient Kridershot!? :D

Comment: @ChaseC i got 2 of them ;D (both > 3,3k dps, one with 1k vita and the other 6AS). And yeah you can be jealous (I found 4 krider since the new patch) but those were my first Krider ever since RoS release so yeah finally :D

Comment: @WizLiz If you're on NA send me a message with your battle.net info - i need to roll with you cuz it sounds like you find good stuff!